# learnyounode file server why put createReadStream() inside createServer()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Both of these snippets work. The only difference is the location of the call to
fs.createReadStream().

It seems to me that it would be more efficient to call it once and assign the result to
a var, rather than calling it on every request.

What's wrong with my thinking?

Answer provided by learnyounode: is it better than mine? If so, why?

```js
    var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'content-type': 'text/plain'
      });

      fs.createReadStream(process.argv[3]).pipe(res)
    });
```

My answer?

```js
var src = fs.createReadStream(process.argv[3])

server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'content-type': 'text/plain'
  })
  src.pipe(response);
});
```

Comment: In this very simplified case, yes, it would make more sense to do this once, however it's probably rare in real world examples to use the argument that the app was executed with in the response of an http request. Instead you would be reading from a database, reading a static file, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. My code works once, not twice, because the stream object gets consumed by the destination.